# Using particular clojure java-wrapper with no project.clj

Tags: java, maven, clojure, leiningen

I try to avoid asking questions that won't help many other people, but I've been at this for far too long to not ask for help. I'm trying to use [this clojure wrapper for a java package](https://github.com/lunkdjedi/clj-ta-lib) as a dependency in my project, but I'm hitting a lot of errors because there's no project.clj.

I've tried using the lein-git-deps plugin with the following keys in my project.clj:

```
:plugins [[lein-git-deps "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"]]
:git-dependencies [["https://github.com/lunkdjedi/clj-ta-lib"]]
```

Running `$ lein git-deps` gives me the following:

```
Setting up dependency for  [https://github.com/lunkdjedi/clj-ta-lib]
Running git pull on  .lein-git-deps
Running git checkout  master  in  .lein-git-deps
```

but nothing changes in my local directory, except now there's an empty `.lein-git-deps/` dir. I'm assuming this didn't work because of the missing `project.clj`.

I've been able to clone the project and call `$ mvn package clojure:repl` which successfully compiled and opened a REPL instance, in which I could use the wrapper perfectly. When I run `$ lein install` it gives me:

```
Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for install
```

but when I run `$ mvn install` it gives me a `BUILD SUCCESS` and  can be found in `~/.m2/repositories/clj-ta-lib`.

I put `:dependencies [[clj-ta-lib/clj-ta-lib "0.0.1"]]` in my `project.clj` and restart the REPL but when I call `(use 'clj-ta-lib.core)` I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.Exception: namespace 'clj-ta-lib.core' not found, compiling:(*cider-repl app*:71:13)
```

Edit:

No longer getting the previous error, but still getting this one:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class com.tictactec.ta.lib.meta.PriceHolder, compiling:(clj_ta_lib/core.clj:13:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff you say you've done sounds pretty reasonable. It's a shame the project isn't hosted on clojars or on maven central, but at least there's a pom to allow you to publish or install it easily yourself. `mvn install` is the right thing to do, and when I clone the project myself and install it, everything installs fine just as you say it does.

However, I can't reproduce your error when trying to use the library. After installing it, I created a new project that depends on the just-installed artifact, and in a repl inside that project, I can use the library's classes just fine. Or, well, I don't know how to *use* these functions as intended, but the functions are available for my use:

```
user=> (use 'clj-ta-lib.core)
nil
user=> ta
#<core$ta clj_ta_lib.core$ta@c668834>
```

So I'd say, make sure you really did follow all the steps you say you did, and that your repl has been started cleanly inside of the project that depends on your library.

Comment: I restarted the process and got another error, one that I saw before but didn't see when I was compiling this post. See the update

Comment: The error in your update is probably a dependency version mismatch. Remove your own dependency on the java library you want to use, and just let the clojure wrapper's transitive dependency do the work for you. In fact, try a project with only *one* dependency, on the clojure wrapper. If that works, start adding dependencies back in until you find the problem.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the guidance, and also I'm enjoying 4Clojure. You could use it as a test-bed for clojure based AGI someday!

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned here, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tictactec/ta-lib/0.4.0 just add [com.tictactec/ta-lib "0.4.0"] to the dependencies 
in your project.clj.

```
:dependencies [[com.tictactec/ta-lib "0.4.0"]]
```

Comment: This question is not about how to get the java library, but how to get a clojure library that provides a clojure-based interface to it.